# What is the easiest way to deserialize human readable time duration in Java?

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, duration, jackson-modules

I need to have configurable timeout for a project, which reads different configs from YAML file.

I noticed that `java.time.Duration` has method [parse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) which is used by Jackson to deserialize duration strings. The problem is that it uses ISO-8601 formatting and expects the duration to have `PnDTnHnMn.nS` format. While it is a good idea to follow standards, asking people provide timeout as `PT10M` is not the best option and `10m` is preferred.

I did write a custom deserializer for duration fields, but seems strange that Jackson can't handle this by default.

What is the easiest way to deserialize human friendly `10m`, `5s` and `1h` to `java.time.Duration` using Jackson ObjectMapper?

Comment: *FYI:* Reading and interpreting input like `10m` is called *parsing*, not deserializing.

Comment: It looks like these inputs are non-standard, for example, how do I know that `m` means minutes and not months? I'd expect that sort of thing to be optionally available by the same library that generates these human friendly strings.

Comment: I don't think Duration even have a month option

Comment: I think just putting `timeout-minutes` in configs is the best option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Easiest" way to deserialize human friendly `10m`, `5s` and `1h` is likely a combination of regex and Java code.

```
public static Duration parseHuman(String text) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\s*(?:(\\d+)\\s*(?:hours?|hrs?|h))?" +
                                "\\s*(?:(\\d+)\\s*(?:minutes?|mins?|m))?" +
                                "\\s*(?:(\\d+)\\s*(?:seconds?|secs?|s))?" +
                                "\\s*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
                       .matcher(text);
    if (! m.matches())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not valid duration: " + text);
    int hours = (m.start(1) == -1 ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)));
    int mins  = (m.start(2) == -1 ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(m.group(2)));
    int secs  = (m.start(3) == -1 ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(m.group(3)));
    return Duration.ofSeconds((hours * 60L + mins) * 60L + secs);
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(parseHuman("1h"));
System.out.println(parseHuman("1 hour 200 minutes"));
System.out.println(parseHuman("3600 secs"));
System.out.println(parseHuman("2h3m4s"));
```

*Output*

```
PT1H
PT4H20M
PT1H
PT2H3M4S
```

Comment: Thanks Adreas, good solution. For now I just use: `Duration.parse(("PT" + text).toUpperCase())`, but your solution does cover more cases and fails in a better way.